# how to use unsupported languages in android application?

Tags: android, internationalization

I'm about writing an application which I need to put some text in persian language.
android doesn't support persian by default , is there any way that the program itself do something to show the texts properly ?

Comment: I'm also looking to provide option for unsupported languages(Welsh and Irish). Here's the latest locales supported, I guess if not supported by the system then using the resource framework is out of the question :(

Comment: I thought that they spoke English, in Wales and Ireland. As well as in Scotland,

Answer (score 0):

Well what you could do was to have the user select persian from some menu etc. (they wont have the phone for persian anyway) and then set all text from code.

Answer (score 0):

Use More Locale 2 To Change Your Language to PERSIAN

### I used it and i successfully changed my language to persian

in some new devices (ex: Galaxy Grand 2 - Galaxy S6 And more...)
this app wants an ADB command to change your language
or the easiest way:
This App wants Root Access to change your language
زنده باد ایران و ایرانی تا ابد